# Lightning cable pitted contacts fix?

Tags: iphone, contacts, power, lightning

Lightning cables are expensive, and I have 2 of them which are in great shape except that they are failing because of pitted contacts. That is, the gold metal of one of the 8 leads has been removed, probably through arcing as shown in the photo below from [this](https://www.zdnet.com/article/lightning-cables-failing-due-to-corrosion/) website.
[image: photo showing pitted contacts]
My question is: is there a way to fix this without having to keep paying for whole cables?

For example, if there were some epoxy or superglue that was conductive, I wonder if that would make sense? If a suggestion like that makes an expert squirm for some reason I don't understand, I guess that's what I'd like to know.

I just don't like wasting.

Comment: I don't know the answer. I would be concerned, however, because any conductive material added to the plug contacts would make the contacts thicker, and the increased thickness could stress the matching socket contacts in the phone or other device. Replacing the cable, I imagine, would be less expensive than having to replace a device's Lightning socket.

Comment: Conductive paint isn't all that adhesive; subjected to that kind of insertion force it will give out first try. I'd agree with David & swap them up for new ones. Are they real Apple cables? I've never seen a lightning connector corrode like that. I must have a dozen here, some as old as the first lightning connector - iPhone 5, 2012 - which show no signs at all.

Comment: Yes, real Apple cables. Google search; many have experienced this with Apple parts, such as here https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4363224 It makes sense to me since arcing is not unexpected if there's a variety of electrical sources throughout the world and dust/moisture can be present between electrodes -- it seems to happen at just THAT pin -- the problem of gunk accumulating in that port is well documented, with photos and video if you search for it. My thought was applying a conductive glue and then sanding to level things out again. I bet someone out there would know about this.

Comment: Yes, I've read about it - I've just never had it happen, over a dozen cables & 7 years... so the 'dust/damp/gunk' is probably relevant... get it wet it will misbehave. There is no way to re-plate a contact short of a full industrial process. Conductive paint will last literally one insertion. Just give up now, buy new cables & don't keep them in unsuitable conditions.